# How to read the output from an interactive program without it scrolling off the screen?

Tags: centos, fdisk

I am running `fdisk` on a device and I'm trying to list the supported partition types. The problem is that it immediately scrolls off the screen and I can't see it.

I was using the latest Fedora on someone's Macbook yesterday and fdisk would pause with a `:` (like the output of `less` and allow scrolling or `q` to break from the output.

I am running CentOS 7.5 in text mode from a minimal install on a VGA monitor connected through an HDMI adapter to the system.

Is this a limitation of my terminal, being in text mode (fdisk on the Macbook was run in a terminal on GNOME), the fact that it's an older version of fdisk, or something else entirely?

[image]

Comment: doesn't Shift-PageUp work anymore?

Comment: That's a thought - but he's using a MacBook (take a look at the [keyboard](https://gizmodo.com/so-lets-talk-about-the-new-macbook-pro-keyboard-1827635122)).  If it's recent hardware: no, he doesn't have that key :-)

Comment: Oops. But If Fn+Shift+Up doesn't work instead of Shift+PageUp, it's a bug.

Comment: Most terminal emulators have scrollback.

Answer (score 1):

The latest Fedora is newer by a year or two than the latest RHEL 7.  A newer **`fdisk`** is a possibility.

You could work around this by using **`script`** to capture the output, and using **`less`** on the resulting **`typescript`** file (running `fdisk` and `less` separately of course).

You could also use the scrolling feature in `screen` or `tmux`, but those typically are not installed initially on a Linux system — they're optional/extra features.

Comment: He's talking Fedora and CentOS - both do that.

Answer (score 0):

Would

```
fdisk /dev/sdc <<<l | less
```

do?